# Image of a compact metric space under a continous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces, with $X$ compact. Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function. Show that $f(X) \subseteq Y$ is compact.

Proving this using the definition of sequentially compact or the open cover definiton of compactness is quite straightforward. However, the exercise is to also prove this using following definition: $X$ is compact iff every open cover of $X$ has a Lebesgue-number and $X$ is totally bounded.

Back to the problem. Showing $f(X)$ is totally bounded is not too difficult:

Let $\varepsilon > 0, \mathcal{O} = \{B_{\varepsilon}(f(x)) | x \in X\}$ is an open cover of $f(X) \Longrightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{O}} = \{f^{-1} \left( B_{\varepsilon}(f(x)) \right)| x \in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$ and hence has a finite subcover $\tilde{\mathcal{U}} = \{ f^{-1} \left( B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_1)) \right), ..., f^{-1} \left( B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_n)) \right) \} $. Then $\mathcal{U} = \{  B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_1)) , ..., B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_n)) \} $ is a cover of $f(X)$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, $f(X)$ is totally bounded.

Now I'm stumped on how to show every open cover of $f(X)$ has a Lebesgue-number. Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Are you looking for a hint or how to show this? Because just searching Lebesgue number in this website gives plenty of results.

Comment: just a hint on where to start

Comment: What do you know so far about compact spaces? Can you use the extreme value theorem?

Comment: Yes I can. In the lecture we proved a big theorem about compact spaces:

Let $X$ be a metric space TFAE:

1) Every infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation point

2) $X$ is sequentially compact

3) Every complex valued function on $X$ is bounded

4) Every real valued function on $X$ takes minima and maxima

5) Every open cover of $X$ has a Lebesgue number and $X$ is totally bounded 

6) Every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover

7) $X$ is totally bounded and complete

8) Every family of pairwise disjoint closed subsets of $X$ has an empty intersection

Answer (score 1):

Right now it looks like you're using the open-cover definition of compactness in your proof for totally bounded, so here's a sketch of how to proceed without ever appealing to the finite-subcover definition of compactness.

Take the open cover $\mathcal U=\{B(x,\epsilon):x\in f(X)\}$ of $f(X)$, then consider their pre-image $\mathcal U'$ in $X$. Since $X$ has a Lebesgue number, there is some $\delta$ where every subset of $X$ with diameter less than $\delta$ is contained in some member of $\mathcal U'$. By totally bounded, we know there is a finite collection $\mathcal V'$ of open balls of diameter $\delta/2$ covering $X$; therefore each ball in $\mathcal V'$ is contained within some member of $\mathcal U'$.

Considering $\mathcal V'$ will allow you to obtain a finite subcover $\mathcal V$ of $\mathcal U$, in turn witnessing totally bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Given an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $f(X)$, find a finite open subcover $\mathcal{U'}=\{ U_1,...,U_k \}$ of it. You should show that $\mathcal{U}'$ has a Lebesgue number. Consider balls in $f(X)$ with respect to the induced metric.

Note that $B_{r}(y)\subseteq U_j$ if and only if $d(y, C_j)\geq r$ where $C_j:=f(X)\setminus U_j $. You need to find a $\delta>0$, such that for all $y\in f(X)$, it must be that $d(y,C_j)\geq \delta$ for some $j$. Note also that $f_j(y)=d(y,C_j)$ is continuous for all $j$.

*I hope you can see how to use this and that this is not too obvious a hint.*

Comment: Isn't this sort-of cheating? It is true that open-cover compactness implies any covering has a Lebesgue number, but then you are really proving that the continuous image of a set which is open cover compact is again open-cover compact, and using that to deduce that the image has a Lebesgue number.

Comment: Well the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact. Also, a compact set has the Lebesgue number property. So this is just using what you know already.

Comment: Ah, but then you need to show that a totally bounded metric space with the Lebesgue number property is compact. Admittedly, that's not terribly hard to prove.